# curl file upload with semicolons in filename

Tags: macos, file-upload, curl, escaping, filenames

I'm implementing an automated, command line file uploader using curl to a servlet.

The problem is, I've got tens of thousands of files with semicolons (;) in the filenames. I'm well aware of the annoyance of this but it is a legacy app that continues to produce new files each day. Renaming is not really an option for compatibility reasons downstream.

I've tried quoting, escaping, converting to "%3b", fully qualifying the path... the obvious stuff... but nothing seems to work, and it fails to send from the client side. I'm on my mac (bundled curl version 7.21.3) but that shouldn't make a difference?

Any ideas?

```
macbookpro:~$ curl -F upload=@"my file.txt" http://localhost:8080/data/upload
ok
macbookpro:~$ curl -F upload=@"my;file.txt" http://localhost:8080/data/upload
curl: (26) failed creating formpost data
macbookpro:~$ curl -F upload=@"my\;file.txt" http://localhost:8080/data/upload
curl: (26) failed creating formpost data
macbookpro:~$ curl -F upload=@"my\\;file.txt" http://localhost:8080/data/upload
curl: (26) failed creating formpost data
macbookpro:~$
```

Comment: Other possible solutions here: http://superuser.com/q/590202/371458

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`curl` uses `;` to separate type (or other directives) from the actual name, so I'd simply use stdin instead:

```
cat 'my;file.txt' | curl -F upload=@- http://localhost:8080/data/upload
```

You may possibly add `filename=` directive as well if desired (but without the semicolon in the name!).

Comment: *Smacks head against table*. Despite 20 years doing this stuff I never even considered stdin this instance. Genius. I did need the filename directive in my case, so for googlers:

`curl -F upload=@-\;filename=xyz http://localhost:8080/data/upload < my\;file.txt 
`
... worked great.

Answer (score -1):

According to CURL man pages, when you have `;` or `,` in your form data(file or raw) you should always enclose it in double quotes. 
[CURL MAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0w19.png)

So just enclose the filename in double quotes and it should work

Comment: Isn't the OP already doing that? `-F upload=@"my;file.txt"`. Or are you referring to a different approach? If so, a code sample might help avoid confusion.

Comment: try enclosing upload=.... inside single quote, edited prev response.. checkout the CURL MAN link