# Curl - Use comma in filenames - Filemaker

Tags: curl, filemaker, synology

I´m trying to connect Filemaker with Synology NAS.

I have a script with all working - but I have problems with comma.

To upload a file in Synology I have to use multipart/form-data. It is working for now using Insert from URL, a in cURL options the parameters. Is working but not with the filename with comma.

```
-X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "path=/Despacho/Despacho/CINE/ARCHIVO/PRUEBAS BORRAR/02_EQUIPO TÉCNICO/04_CONTRATOS/02_CERTIFICADO FIRMA" 
-F "create_parents=true" 
-F "overwrite=true" 
-F "file=@$fileToupload;filename=x,20yz"
```

$fileToupload is the file (inside a container in filemaker)

I´m reading this options but nothing.

[Curl request with comma in the directory name in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542548/curl-request-with-comma-in-the-directory-name-in-bash)

[curl file upload with semicolons in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745611/curl-file-upload-with-semicolons-in-filename)

https://superuser.com/questions/590202/upload-a-file-with-a-comma-in-its-name-with-curl

https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2006-06/0077.html

There are a option to send multipart/form-data without cURL in filemaker. Or to solve this problems with commas.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried this and nothing: -F "file=@"$fileToupload";filename="x,20yz ""

Comment: And with this:  -F "file=@$fileToupload;filename="x,20yz "" ---- The result: "file":"FMTEMPFM1513_3651.pdf"

Comment: This should work. -F  "file=@$fileToupload;filename=\"x,20yz\"" . Note: I started with double quote, also ended with double quote. Also after filename I used double quote preceded by backslash, both in start and in end.

Comment: Sorry, I loss. In filemaker I use:
"-X POST
-H \"Content-Type: multipart/form-data\"
-F \"path=" & $path & "\"
-F \"create_parents=true"  & "\"
-F \"overwrite=true"  & "\"
-F \"file=@$fileToupload;filename=\"x,20yz\"\"
"

Comment: If I use this (Filemaker Structure): 
-F \"file=@$fileToupload;filename=\"x,20yz\"\"
The result is: {"data":{"blSkip":false,"file":"FMTEMPFM1513_3663.pdf","pid":28564,"progress":1},"success":true}

Comment: What does this give you? -F "file=@$fileToupload;filename=\"x,20yz\""

Comment: Can you copy paste this and tell me the result?      -F "file=@$fileToupload;filename=\"x,20yz\""

Comment: Sorry:
Filemaker: -F \"file=@$fileToupload;filename=\"x,20yz\"\"
Like I really send: -F "overwrite=true" -F "file=@$fileToupload;filename="x,20yz""

Comment: I don't see that you have used my code. you have used something else

Comment: This is wrong \"x,20yz\"\" The double quote in the end needs not be escaped. Just use \"x,20yz\" and then " to end the  "file

Comment: It´s working¡¡¡¡ Thank you much Madhurjya. I cant send just use your code in Filemaker, I need convert. But you have right. Thanks again

Comment: Consider posting an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Madhurjya I have the solution. You have to use \" in start and in the end of the filename.

```
-X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "path=/Despacho/Despacho/CINE/ARCHIVO/01_PRODUCCION AUDIOVISUAL/PRUEBAS BORRAR/02_EQUIPO TÉCNICO/04_CONTRATOS/02_CERTIFICADO FIRMA" 
-F "create_parents=true" 
-F "overwrite=true" 
-F "file=@$fileToupload;filename=\"x,20yz.pdf\""
```

The code in Filemaker:

```
"-X POST
-H \"Content-Type: multipart/form-data\"
-F \"path=" & $path & "\"
-F \"create_parents=true"  & "\"
-F \"overwrite=true"  & "\"
-F \"file=@$fileToupload;filename=\\\"x,20yz.pdf\\\"\"
"
```

Thanks again for your help.